# Symfony2 is it possible to remove session variable with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, session

When I am displaying selected products that are saved in sessions I have a button with which I want to remove a specific product if i dont need it. Can I achieve that with javascript? If not what are other solutions to this problem?

I have heard that you cant set session variables with javascript so probably the same goes with removing them, but I have heard that you can do something with ajax to remove them?? Anyway im displaying my products like this(for now im only showing the price of the product dynamically):

```
{% for item in items %}
    <tr>
        <td><img width="60" src="{{ asset('bundles/mpFrontend/assets/products/4.jpg') }}" alt=""/></td>

        <td>{{ item.model }}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="input-append"><input class="span1" style="max-width:34px" placeholder="1" id="appendedInputButtons" size="16" type="text">
                <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-minus"></i></button>
                <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="removeItem(item.id)"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>$120.00</td>
        <td>$25.00</td>
        <td>$15.00</td>
        <td>$110.00</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**UPDATE** This is what I have done already:

removeAction in controller:

```
public function removeAction($itemId)
{
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $session->remove();
    return $this->render('MpShopBundle:Frontend:product_summary.html.twig');    
}
```

Controller routing:

```
removeItem:
  pattern:  /remove
  defaults: { _controller: MpShopBundle:Homepage:remove }
```

The script:

```
<script>

    $(".btn btn-danger").click(function(){  
        var itemId = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ path('removeItem') }}",
            data: { itemId: itemId }
        });

</script>
```

Pressing on the button doesnt do anything and im not surprised since this is my first time really using javascript i guess i did something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can with ajax !

1. Create your action in a controller which remove a given product of your session.

a Sample code :

```
ProductController extends Controller{
   ...

   public function removeItemAction($itemId){

         //find here your session where you save the item.

        //and remove it

        //return a response depending on what you want in the format that you want (json,xml,...)
        return new Response("...");
   }
}
```

2.Create your javascript code which listen the action and send a request ajax to the precedent url. (if you use jQuery , see $.ajax )

3. update your DOM (with deleting the right elements or load any html that you want ).

Comment: Since I am fairly new to programming can you explain the first part more briefly?

Comment: Ok. The variable $itemId has to be specified in the javascript function, then I remove the session based on the id. The response part is not clear to me.  Is it the same as render?

Comment: Response = render . it depends on what you need, it can be the "html" that you will see, or just a "boolean" to tell to your script if it was really done  (and remove your item in javascript)

Comment: this is the idea, how can i help you ? (except you should remove the item of your session, not all your session ). and you should remove the $itemId of your methodAction ( and take it from Request object )

Answer (score 0):

Using ONLY Javascript, you can't. 
Your PHP session can only be accessed through php. The only thing you can do is create a function in php that removes whatever you want from the session, and call it from javascript using ajax calls like @MouradK said